# Btrfs reports "ERROR: minimum size for each btrfs device is 131072000", but my drives are much larger

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, btrfs, virtual-file-system

I have x2 2TB drives that I want to make a single Raid0 logical drive.  The error I'm getting doesn't make any sense.  Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

I use

```
lsblk -o name,mountpoint,size,uuid,fstype,model,serial
```

I see both devices are mounted, and the size is the same (953.4G*).  I know because when I installed them, I had different fstypes on them, so I changed them both to ext4, then used `dd` to make them identical in terms of partitioning.

*Yes, I know this partition isn't using the full size of this drive right now.

I'm trying to use btrfs,

```
mkfs.btrfs -f -d raid0 -m raid0 zdata1 zdata2
```

but I get the error

> ERROR: 'zdata1' is too small to make a usable filesystem
>
> ERROR: minimum size for each btrfs is 131072000

Answer (score 1):

I've tested using loop devices:

Create images:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test1 bs=1 count=1 seek=4294967295
dd if=/dev/zero of=test2 bs=1 count=1 seek=4294969343
```

Add them as loop devices:

```
losetup -f test1
losetup -f test2
```

Check for the loop devices used:

```
losetup | grep test
/dev/loop8    0      0     1  0 /home/davod/test1     0     512
/dev/loop9    0      0     1  0 /home/davod/test2     0     512
```

Then, create the BTRFS pool:

```
mkfs.btrfs -f /dev/loop8 /dev/loop9
```

It worked for me.

If you don't have important data on the disks, just use ZFS, using the entries devices, and use a separated device (a SSD) for boot (EFI partition if the machine has it, and ext4 for GRUB), and empty partitions for L2ARC and ZIL).

Comment: Sounds like a comment to me. But I understand why you...

Comment: Them, please clarify if you're already using the pool (or the disks) or you want to create it from scratch. I've updated the ansver above, as it will also help others.

I personally prefer ZFS.